# Return object type C

Tags: c

So i am working on my assignment and i got stuck on a piece of code.

```
struct image* createImg(unsigned int dim1, unsigned int dim2){

    int **a=NULL;
    int j;
    a=malloc(dim1*sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0;i<dim1;i++)
    {
        a[i]=malloc(dim2*sizeof(int));
        for (j=0;j<dim2;j++)
            a[i][j]=0;
    }
    return a; //error here
//return 0; 
}
```

The return type is an image Object. I am to compute width/height for a 2D array in this particular function. How can i return this value?

This is done in C

Update:

header file

`struct image{
    int **a;
};`

and i changed a bit of the implementation

```
struct image* createWhiteimg(unsigned int dim1, unsigned int dim2){ 


   struct image img;
   img.a = NULL;


  //  int **a=NULL;
    int j;
    img.a=malloc(dim1*sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0;i<dim1;i++)
    {
        img.a[i]=malloc(dim2*sizeof(int));
        for (j=0;j<dim2;j++)
            img.a[i][j]=0;
    }
   return &img;
}
```

Comment: Please post the image struct definition.

Comment: Since an `struct image*` is not an `int**`, that obviously won't work. You have two options for returning `a`, both of which involve changing the function return type: `int**` or `void*`. Whether *either* are appropriate is up to you, since we have no earthly clue what a `struct image` even is, nor why you would think a pointer to one would be somehow equivalent to a `int**`.

Comment: It's my first time programming in C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MCVE should look something more like this:

```
struct image* createImg(unsigned int dim1, unsigned int dim2){
    int **a=NULL;
    return a; //error here
}
```

Please put more effort into minimalising your MCVEs in the future.

It should become blatantly obvious from this example that the type of `a` is `int **`, yet the return type is `struct image *`. Those two types are incompatible, hence the error.

> How can i return this value?

You need to work out how to return a `struct image *` value, for a start.

Once you've done that, work out how to allocate a `struct image` to point at with that `struct image *`...

... and finally, you may want to insert your initial values into that `struct image`.

---

> It's my first time programming in C

You can't learn to program in C like this! Unguided trial and error will lead to much headaches, as you'll be learning an *implementation-specific* language that's *similar* to C, yet differs in subtle (and possibly disastrous) ways. This will become evident when you use a *different* implementation.

You should read a book such as K&R2E, do the exercises, and *then* start working on code like this.

---

The kind of harm caused by *not sharpening your axe before you cut into your tree* is that you use **way too much effort**! So you want to allocate something analoguous to a two-dimensional array? Watch this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void create_image(size_t x, size_t y, int (**array)[y]) {
    *array = malloc(x * sizeof **array);
}

int main(void) {
    int (*array)[42];
    create_image(13, 42, &array);
}
```

This ought to strengthen the advice that you need a better book...

Answer (score 0):

Few inputs, x and y has to unsigned i.e. 0-255 (by default) for an image array. But when you subtract such matrix, you may get negative values and thats when you can save the resultant in an integer size matrix. You can use 'Mat' object in openCV as an example.

Avoid using dynamic memory and rather use stack from performance point of view. But when you use stack then its not as big as heap, hence data type size matters a lot when the image dimension are large it really matters.